# How can I draw images, lines, etc. on google maps

Tags: ajax, html, google-maps-api-3

I'm investigating how I might best create an app that allows drawing of arbitrary shapes, images, etc. on google maps, based on lat/lon coords of the shapes or coords/rotations for images. Surprisingly I haven't found anything out there that offers much in the way of flexibility. Scribble-maps has created something close to what I'd aim for, but they're using flash. I'd ideally like to build something that draws on the google maps html map.

I suppose I could build a div, lay it on top of the map, and if I can listen on the map scroll/zoom events I should be able to figure out how to do everything myself. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use overlays, check the [Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays).

There's an example of mouse interaction to draw lines in the **Polyline Arrays** section. To show images have a look at the **Ground Overlays** section.

Comment: Thanks, I looked through the APIs but I didn't notice the ground and custom overlays; I thought the only way was the map overlay which involved rendering full tiles which isn't what I wanted. I'm still not sure how best to create my own drawing tool. I wish the google overlays drawing library was open source!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very a late response, but we have launched an API for Scribble Maps. You can check it out at http://www.scribblemaps.com/api/